# How to upgrade AWS RDS parameter/option groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am running RDS mariadb instances with custom parameter groups and option groups, and now I am upgrading them from 10.3 to 10.4. The problem is during upgrade, I need specify a new parameter group that's based on 10.4.

My question is how do I upgrade my existing parameter group of 10.3 to 10.4.
Do I just create a new parameter group from default 10.4 and modify it. Is there an easy way to identify all the parameters that have non-default values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are upgrading your db version, you do have to create a new parameter group for that specific version.

The easiest way to do this is to create a new parameter group with the new version, then select both your old group and your new one in the UI. Once both are selected, there is a "compare" option. This will pull up the differences in your two parameter groups, so that you can see what you modified and then make the changes to the new one.

It is not very ideal - I wish they had a way to upgrade the parameter groups but it seems that create new -> compare is the most viable route.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new custom parameter group at the version you are updating to and re-modify all the custom things you had in your previous group.

The other answer is pretty correct, but I wanted to add that if you wanted to see what is non-default you should compare your **10.3 custom parameter group to a default 10.3 parameter group to see whats changed**. Comparing 10.3 to 10.4 could show you new *default* things in 10.4 that didn't exist in 10.3 that may seem like you added/changed those, which is not the case.